# Hiding all the values for a field on a pivot table apart from one

Tags: vba, pivot-table, field, hide

I'm struggling with something that should be simple and can't seem to google my way out of it.

I have a Sheet called "HL", with a Pivot table called PivotTable1
Each time I refresh the table it could bring in various values in field called "Role".

I want to end up with only one role showing which = "PO",

I've tried to find a way to look through all the values to turn then off and then turn that one back on (sounds inefficient, but with my limited knowledge I hoped I get there, but I'm struggling).

I do have some example code, but they are from others and don't work for this application

All suggestions gratefully received.
Thanks

Comment: can you share at least a screenshot. Have your tried to define segments?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for replying.

I've just worked out a way to do it that works,

To only show specific values in a Pivot, that you want to define, this will do it.

```
            Dim PivotField As PivotField
            Dim filterValue As String
        
                 With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("ROle")
                      Set PivotField = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Role")
                      filterValue = "PO"               
                      PivotField.CurrentPage = filterValue 
                End With
```